# pywintypes27.dll not found using Apache, Django, pywin32, Python2.7 and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, pywin32, django-mssql

I have a Django application using django-mssql to communicate w/ SQL Server.

This works just fine in the dev server (runserver) but under Apache/mod-wsgi, I get a error related to it trying to find a .dll which does exist:

```
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes27.dll)
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py in __import_pywin32_system_module__, line 98
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin\httpd.exe
```

I used ActivePython2.7.2, mod_wsgi, pywin32 Build 216 and Django1.3.1, all of 32 bits

pywintypes27.dll exists in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 instead of C:\Windows\System32 as expected in my 64 bit windows 7

Thanks in advance

This is the same question as [django-mssql not working in Apache w/ mod-wsgi, but works fine in dev server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064243/django-mssql-not-working-in-apache-w-mod-wsgi-but-works-fine-in-dev-server) but that answer didn't help me cause I have installed 32 bits pywin32, I am new to stackoverflow and hope it is right to ask as a new question rather than hijack people's thread.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Move files:

- pythoncom27.dll
- pythoncomloader27.dll
- pywintypes27.dll

from "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32"

to

"C:\Python27"

Hope it helps.

Comment: Which suggests you didn't install Python for all users when you installed it. There is a checkbox on the installer or in batch install config file if doing it that way.

Comment: Thanks for it! I will make sure I install it for all users next time.

Answer (score 0):

Install **pywin32-218.win32-py2.7.exe** in machines of 32 or 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

For those who installed pywin32 via pip : check that you have done it outside a virtualenv.

If you've done it inside virtualenv, we can get this kind of error.

Prefer binarie installation : [See Mark Amery response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863056/how-to-install-pywin32-module-in-windows-7)